# Algorithms - Find duration of overlapping intervals in a cyclic world (24 hours)

Tags: java, algorithm, intervals, overlap

I've been trying to figure out the algorithm for finding the number of overlapping hours between two time ranges, for example:

[image]

Should return 12.

And

[image]

Should return 4.

So please help me fill in the gaps in creating the following function:

```
public static Long findOverlappingInterval(Long startTime1, Long endTime1,
                                           Long startTime2, Long endTime2){ 
    // Any suggestions?
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm aware of the solution of creating two binary arrays, using `AND` and summing up the result. 
Meaning:

[image]

But that would not help my specific needs since i want to use the idea of the algorithm for a solr query, so **using arrays and binary operators is not an option for me**.

Comment: In second example, how is that broken interval? How would you represent it in startTime and endTime?

Comment: @RahulJain `startTime = 12`, `endTime = 2`. it's a cyclic world.

Comment: I've been trying to post code for you but StackOverflow keeps warning me that indentation is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Surprisingly many answers in a short time...</sub>

I followed the same idea that was already proposed in other answers: When start time `s` is smaller than the end time `e`, then the result can be broken down into two separate computations, for the ranges `[s,24]` and `[0,e]`.

This can be done "mutually" so there are only 3 simple cases to consider, and the remaining ones can be done with recursive calls.

However, I tried to

- consider the fact that (according to the images), the end points should be **inclusive** (!)
- Add some more test cases
- Visualize the configurations nicely :-)

This is the result as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
public class OverlappingIntervals
{
    private static final long INTERVAL_SIZE = 24;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test(6,23, 2,17);
        test(0,12, 12,2);

        test(11,4, 12,3);
        test(12,4, 11,3);
    }

    private static void test(
        long s0, long e0, long s1, long e1)
    {
        System.out.println(createString(s0, e0, s1, e1));
        System.out.println(findOverlappingInterval(s0, e0, s1, e1));
    }

    private static String createString(
        long s0, long e0, long s1, long e1)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(createString(s0, e0, "A")).append("\n");
        sb.append(createString(s1, e1, "B"));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String createString(long s, long e, String c)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<INTERVAL_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (s < e)
            {
                if (i >= s && i <= e)
                {
                    sb.append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.append(".");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (i <= e || i >= s)
                {
                    sb.append(c);
                }
                else 
                {
                    sb.append(".");
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }



    public static long findOverlappingInterval(
        long s0, long e0, long s1, long e1)
    {
        return compute(s0, e0+1, s1, e1+1);
    }

    public static long compute(
        long s0, long e0, long s1, long e1)
    {
        if (s0 > e0)
        {
            return 
                compute(s0, INTERVAL_SIZE, s1, e1) +
                compute(0, e0, s1, e1);
        }
        if (s1 > e1)
        {
            return 
                compute(s0, e0, s1, INTERVAL_SIZE) +
                compute(s0, e0, 0, e1);
        }
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(e0, e1) - Math.max(s0, s1));
    }
}
```

The first two test cases are the ones that have been given in the question, and they properly print `12` and `4`, respectively. The remaining two are intended for testing other overlap configurations:

```
......AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
..BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB......
12
AAAAAAAAAAAAA...........
BBB.........BBBBBBBBBBBB
4
AAAAA......AAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBB........BBBBBBBBBBBB
16
AAAAA.......AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBB.......BBBBBBBBBBBBB
16
```

However, note that further test configurations may have to be created in order to cover all possible cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without creating an array, just calculating intersections between intervals. There are three cases:

1. No splitted intervals.
2. One splitted interval.
3. Both intervals are splitted.

You can solve the problem of splitted intervals as two separate intervals. Using recursion you can do this easily:

```
public static Long findOverlappingInterval(Long startTime1, Long endTime1, Long startTime2, Long endTime2)
{
    if (startTime1 < endTime1 && startTime2 < endTime2) 
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(endTime2, endTime1) - Math.max(startTime1, startTime2) + 1);
    else
    {
        if (startTime1 < endTime1) 
            return findOverlappingInterval(startTime1, endTime1, 0L, endTime2) + 
                   findOverlappingInterval(startTime1, endTime1, startTime2, 23L);
        else if (startTime2 < endTime2) 
            return findOverlappingInterval(0L, endTime1, startTime2, endTime2) + 
                   findOverlappingInterval(startTime1, 23L, startTime2, endTime2);
        else
        {
            return findOverlappingInterval(0L, endTime1, 0L, endTime2) +
                   findOverlappingInterval(0L, endTime1, startTime2, 23L) +
                   findOverlappingInterval(startTime1, 23L, 0L, endTime2) +
                   findOverlappingInterval(startTime1, 23L, startTime2, 23L);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the case that both intervals are splitted does not have to be covered explicitly: When the first cases are treated with recursive calls, it will never (have to) arrive at the final `else` case. Nevertheless, +1 for the clear description and (working and efficient) solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, for interval `(a, b)` which `(a > b)`,  we can easily break it into two intervals

```
(a , 23) and (0, b)
```

So, the problem become finding the overlapping between `(a , b)` and `(a1, b1)` with `a <= b and a1 <= b1`

So, there are four cases:

- `b < a1` or `b1 < a` , which means there is no overlapping, return 0
- `a <= a1 && b1 <= b`, which means `(a, b)` contains `(a1, b1)`, return `b1 - a1 + 1`
- `a1 <= a && b <= b1`, which means `(a1, b1)` contains `(a, b)`, return `b - a + 1`
- Last case is `(a, b)` and `(a1, b1)` overlapped part of each interval, that overlapping interval is `(max(a1, a), min(b, b1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Start times must be smaller than end times */
public static int findOverlappingInterval(int startTime1, int endTime1, int startTime2, int endTime2) {
    int overlappingTime = 0;
    int[] time1 = new int[Math.abs(endTime1 - startTime1)];
    for (int i1 = startTime1; i1 < endTime1; i1++) {
        time1[i1 - startTime1] = i1;
    }
    int[] time2 = new int[Math.abs(endTime2 - startTime2)];
    for (int i2 = startTime2; i2 < endTime2; i2++) {
        time2[i2 - startTime2] = i2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < time1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < time2.length; j++) {
            if (time1[i] == time2[j]) {
                overlappingTime++;
            }
        }
    }
    return overlappingTime;
}
```

This method should work for what you want it to do. It worked for me.
I am unsure about the wrapping part though.

*EDIT*

```
/** Returns the overlap between the four time variables */
public static int findOverlappingInterval(int startTime1, int endTime1, int startTime2, int endTime2) {
    int overlappingTime = 0;

    // First time
    int time1Length = 0;
    if (endTime1 < startTime1) {
        time1Length = 24 - startTime1;
        time1Length += endTime1;
    }
    int[] time1;
    if (time1Length == 0) {
        time1 = new int[Math.abs(endTime1 - startTime1)];
        for (int i1 = startTime1; i1 < endTime1; i1++) {
            time1[i1 - startTime1] = i1;
        }
    } else {
        time1 = new int[time1Length];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < endTime1; i1++) {
            time1[count] = i1;
            count++;
        }
        for (int i1 = startTime1; i1 < 24; i1++) {
            time1[count] = i1;
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Second time
    int time2Length = 0;
    if (endTime2 < startTime2) {
        time2Length = 24 - startTime2;
        time2Length += endTime2;
    }
    int[] time2;
    if (time2Length == 0) {
        time2 = new int[Math.abs(endTime2 - startTime2)];
        for (int i2 = startTime2; i2 < endTime2; i2++) {
            time2[i2 - startTime2] = i2;
        }
    } else {
        time2 = new int[time2Length];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < endTime2; i2++) {
            time2[count] = i2;
            count++;
        }
        for (int i2 = startTime2; i2 < 24; i2++) {
            time2[count] = i2;
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Overlap calculator
    for (int i = 0; i < time1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < time2.length; j++) {
            if (time1[i] == time2[j]) {
                overlappingTime++;
            }
        }
    }
    return overlappingTime;
}
```

This new code should do what you want. It loops around a 24 hour period.

Comment: I can't make the `/** Start times must be smaller than end times */` assumption. in the second example `startTime` is bigger than `endTime`.

Comment: I have added a loop to it now.

Comment: it looks inefficient, there should exist a less naive solution

Comment: I agree. That is what I came up with though. xD. It works. That is what counts. Unless it is actually causing an issue. Also, sometimes simple tasks require complicated solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link here: [Ideone link](http://ideone.com/wKxdR0)

> <sub>EDIT: Inserted the code from the link here:</sub>

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static Long min(Long a,Long b){
        return ((a)<(b)?(a):(b));
    }
    public static Long max(Long a,Long b){
        return ((a)>(b)?(a):(b));
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Long s1=6L,e1=23L,s2=2L,e2=17L,ans=0L;
        Boolean broken1,broken2;
        broken1=(s1<=e1)?false:true;
        broken2=(s2<=e2)?false:true;
        if(broken1){
            if(broken2)
                ans=min(e1,e2)+1 + 23-max(s1,s2)+1;
            else{
                if(e1>=s2) ans+=(min(e1,e2)-s2+1);
                if(s1<=e2) ans+=(e2-max(s1,s2)+1);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(broken2){
                if(e2>=s1) ans+=(min(e1,e2)-s1+1);
                if(s2<=e1) ans+=(e1-max(s1,s2)+1);
            }
            else{
                if(e1<s2 || e2<s1) ans=0L;
                else ans=min(e1,e2)-max(s1,s2)+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans+"");
    }
}
```